# Choosing among radio buttons and Text Field

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 radio buttons. All of them have different values. I also have one text field, in case I need a different value, I can enter that value on that text field.

```
    <form action="" onsubmit="return doSubmit(this)">
    <input type="radio" name="url" value="https://example.com/fee/25"> $25
    <input type="radio" name="url" value="https://example.com/fee/50"> $50
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

and here is the Javascript I've found to make radio buttons working

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function doSubmit(form) {
    var urls = form['url'];
    var i = urls && urls.length;
    while (i--) {
      if (urls[i].checked) {
        window.location = urls[i].value;
      }
    }
document.getElementById("amount").value;
    return false;
  }

  </script>
```

I have one text field:

```
<input type="text" name="amount" size="10" id="amount" value="">
```

Ok. If the amount is entered, then I need to use this code:

```
document.getElementById("amount").value
```

But how to make it working with radio buttons? I have created this JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var link = "https://example.com/fee/";
    var input= document.getElementById('amount');
    input.onchange=input.onkeyup= function() {
        link.search= encodeURIComponent(input.value);
      };
</script>
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your time. I love and enjoy learning from experts.

Comment: Do your URLs all follow the same pattern, like in your example (starting with `https://example.com/fee/`?

Comment: Yes! But different amounts are added according to the value of radio buttons or text field. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a separate radio button for the text input:

```js
var options = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[name=url]"));

amount.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    options[0].checked = true; // If textbox gets focus, check that radio button
});

options[0].addEventListener('change', function() {
    amount.focus(); // if first radio button gets checked, focus on textbox.
});

function doSubmit(form) {
    // get checked value, replace empty value with input text
    var value = options.find( option => option.checked ).value || amount.value; 
    window.location = "https://example.com/fee/" + value;
    return false;
};
```

```html
<form action="" onsubmit="return doSubmit(this)">
    <input type="radio" name="url" value="" checked>
         $<input type="text" name="amount" size="5" id="amount" value="" >
    <input type="radio" name="url" value="25"> $25
    <input type="radio" name="url" value="50"> $50
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This is definitely a cleaner solution than mine. Maybe you could add an `onkeyup` handler for `amount` to set the value of `options[0]` instead of setting the value in `doSubmit` (just to illustrate the relationship between the input and radio button)

Comment: That is possible, but `onkeyup` is not safe: one can do amazing stuff just with the mouse, context menu or other weird devices. The `input` event would be suitable, but then you keep copying the value on every change, while it really is only needed once -- at submission.

Comment: Both of them are great to improve coding skills. I could learn a lot from them. I didnt't even know that onkeyup is not safe. Do you mean, website could be hacked if someone try to use it?

Comment: That's very true, I never considered that before! Do you think `onchange` or `oninput` would handle all cases?

Also, I completely agree that it is unnecessary to copy the value on every change. However, it is nice to have pseudo data-binding :)

Comment: In this case, 'unsafe' means that you can not guarantee that the value entered in the text field will necessarily be reflected in the value of the radio button. For example, if I copy-pasted some text into the input using my right click menu, the onkeyup event would never fire, which would mean my radio button would not update with the correct value. It is best to reduce the amount of logic, especially when handling forms.

Comment: Indeed, with "not safe" I did not mean in a security way: just that you would not catch all changes to the input and could navigate to the wrong URL as a consequence. The `input` event catches all changes independent of the input method, it just has lacking support in older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the url as the value for the radio buttons, consider using the value you wish to pass to the url:

```js
function doSubmit(form) {
    var endpoint = "https://example.com/fee/";
    
    // gets the values of input elements that were selected
    var checkedValues = Array.from(form.amounts)
      .filter(radio => radio.checked)
      .map(radio => radio.value);
    
    // if a radio button was checked, use its value
    // otherwise, use the value in the text field
    var amount = checkedValues.length ? 
        checkedValues[0] : form.amount.value;
    
    console.log('redirecting to: ', endpoint + amount);
    return false;
}

// uncheck radio buttons when text is entered
function uncheck() {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="amounts"]'))
    .forEach(radio => radio.checked = false);
}
```

```html
<form action="" onsubmit="return doSubmit(this)">
  <input type="radio" name="amounts" value="25"> $25
  <input type="radio" name="amounts" value="50"> $50
  <input type="text" name="amount" onkeyup="uncheck()">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Edit: Wow I completely forgot you could use the :checked attribute as a css selector. In this case, the code becomes quite simple:

```js
function doSubmit(form) {
    // select checked inputs with the specified name attribute
    var checkedRadio = document.querySelector('input[name="amounts"]:checked')
    
    // if we have a radio button that is checked, use its value
    // otherwise, use the text input's value
    var amount = checkedRadio ? checkedRadio.value : form.amount.value;
    
    window.location = 'https://example.com/fee/' + amount;
    return false;
}

// uncheck radio buttons when text is entered
function uncheck() {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="amounts"]'))
    .forEach(radio => radio.checked = false);
}
```

```html
<form action="" onsubmit="return doSubmit(this)">
  <input type="radio" name="amounts" value="25"> $25
  <input type="radio" name="amounts" value="50"> $50
  <input type="text" name="amount" onkeyup="uncheck()">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to figure out your code. return doSubmit(this) doesn't provide the console.log('redirecting to: ', endpoint + amount); Nothing happens OnSubmit.

Comment: `console.log` was used just to show the final value. You can set `window.location` instead of just logging the output.